# OpenID in django without local site accounts

Tags: django, openid, django-authentication

I'm working on a django site, which I want the authentication part to work exactly like how Stack Overflow works. A new user comes to the site, they click on "create new account", choose their OpenID provider, get validated, then an account is created for them with "openiduser4356" or something as the username. The user can then go into preferences and change the username to whatever they want. I don't want any kind of local account sign-ups at all.

I pretty much spent all day getting django-authopenid working and it seems the only way this plugin works is by adding OpenID identities to already existing accounts. Heck, you can't even run your site when you have django-authopenid installed unless you have django-registration installed as well...

Before I spend another day wrestling with this thing to try getting it to do what I want, I'd rather just know off the bat if this kind of thing is even possible/a good idea. I noticed that there are a few other OpenID plugins for django out there. Are any of them any better at doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Couldn't you just create the required account when the user logs in, completly hiding any registration / signup process from the user?

Comment: @Tom that could work, but still doesn't solve the django-registration dependency

Answer (score 1):

[django-openid](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid/) does not depend on django-registration.

Answer (score 1):

You might also take a look at a fork of django-openid, [django-openid-consumer](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-consumer/). It works with the most recent python-openid libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using rpxnow.com, check out http://github.com/howthebodyworks/django-rpx/tree/master